# jq : print key and value for each entry in nested object

Tags: json, linux, bash, export-to-csv, jq

This is JSON Object

```
{
    "success": true,
    "terms": "https://coinlayer.com/terms",
    "privacy": "https://coinlayer.com/privacy",
    "timestamp": 1620244806,
    "target": "USD",
    "rates": {
      "611": 0.389165,
      "ABC": 59.99,
      "ACP": 0.014931,
      "ACT": 0.021098,
      "ACT*": 0.017178,
      "ADA": 1.460965
    }
  }
```

I require this type of output:

```
611,0.389165
ABC,59.99
ACP,0.014931
ACT,0.021098
ACT*,0.017178
ADA,1.460965
```

Can somebody help me figure out doing it preferably with **jq**, shell script or command.

Comment: Do you specifically want just the `rates` object? Or are there other sub-objects you want?

Comment: just as mentioned format. Nothing more than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@csv` to generate CSV output from arrays, and `to_entries` to break up the object's elements into said arrays:

```sh
$ jq -r '.rates | to_entries[] | [ .key, .value ] | @csv' input.json
"611",0.389165
"ABC",59.99
"ACP",0.014931
"ACT",0.021098
"ACT*",0.017178
"ADA",1.460965
```

Comment: And to provide the exact output: `... | to_entries[] | "\(.key),\(.value)"`

Comment: @MaulikPipaliyaJoyy `@csv` quotes all strings instead of looking at the contents to see if there's a comma or other character that means the field needs to be quoted. Anything that uses an actual CSV parser to read the results won't care about them being present. But if you really don't want the quotes, see Glenn's comment for a less-robust version using string interpolation.